# Sign up form continues with blank entries

Tags: javascript, html

So I am making a sign up form for a website, and it is not working entirely. Only for the first 5 entries will it not let you proceed till you fill them out, but after city, it still goes through even the the others aren't filled in. I can't figure out what I need to add to prevent it from submitting unless ALL parts are filled out. Please help, thank you.

```
<script>


function validateForm(){
    if ((document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value == "") || (document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value == null))
    {
        alert("First Name is required!");
        return false;
    }

    if ((document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].value == "") || (document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].value == null))
    {
        alert("Last Name is required!");
        return false;
    }

    if ((document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value == "") || (document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value == null))
    {
        alert("Email is required!");
        return false;
    }

    if ((document.forms["myForm"]["street"].value == "") || (document.forms["myForm"]["street"].value == null))
    {
        alert("Street is required!");
        return false;
    }`
    if ((document.forms["myForm"]["city"].value == "") || (document.forms["myForm"]["city"].value == null))
    {
        alert("City is required!");
        return false;
    }

    if ((document.forms["myForm"]["Postal Code"].value == "") || (document.forms["myForm"]["Postal Code"].value == null))
    {
        alert("Postal Code is required!");
        return false;
    }

    if ((document.forms["myForm"]["gender"].value == "") || (document.forms["myForm"]["gender"].value == null))
    {
        alert("Gender is required!");
        return false;
    }

    if ((document.forms["myForm"]["day"].value == "") || (document.forms["myForm"]["day"].value == null))
    {
        alert("Day is required!");
        return false;
    }

    if ((document.forms["myForm"]["year"].value == "") || (document.forms["myForm"]["year"].value == null))
    {
        alert("Year is required!");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And here is the HTML

```
<form name="myForm" action="thanks.html" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm()"/>

<table id="table2" style="margin-top:50px; margin-left:900px; background-image: url(images/roses.jpg);">
<tr>
    <td id="label">First Name:</td>
    <td id="input_fields">
        <input type="text" name="fname" maxlength="15" />
        <i id="star">*</i>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="label">Last Name:</td>
    <td id="input_fields">
        <input type="text" name="lname" maxlength="15" /><i id="star">*</i>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="label">E-Mail:</td>
    <td id="input_fields">
        <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="25" /><i id="star">*</i>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="label">Street Address:</td>
    <td id="input_fields">
        <input type="text" name="street" maxlength="25" /><i id="star">*</i>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="label">City:</td>
    <td id="input_fields">
        <input type="text" name="city" maxlength="25" /><i id="star">*</i>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="label">State:</td>
    <td id="input_fields">
        <input type="text" name="state" maxlength="25" /><i id="star">*</i>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="label">Postal code:</td>
    <td id="input_fields">
        <input type="text" name="Postal code" maxlength="25" /><i id="star">*</i>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="label">Gender:</td>
    <td id="input_fields">
        Male:<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />
        Female:<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />
        Other:<input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="label">Date of Birth:</td>
    <td id="input_fields">
        <select>
            <option></option>
            <option>JAN</option>
            <option>FEB</option>
            <option>MAR</option>
            <option>APR</option>
            <option>MAY</option>
            <option>JUN</option>
            <option>JUL</option>
            <option>AUG</option>
            <option>SEP</option>
            <option>OCT</option>
            <option>NOV</option>
            <option>DEC</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" name="day" maxlength="2" size="4"/>
        <input type="text" name="year" maxlength="4" size="4"/><i id="star">*</i>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td id="input_fields">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Submit" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

### Sign up here!

Comment: you use common id's all over the place but id's are supposed to be unique... try using classes instead

Comment: You've got a back tick right after your street input validation `if` statement in your JavaScript. Remove that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the postal code validation with the following:

```
if ((document.forms["myForm"]["postalCode"].value == "") || (document.forms["myForm"]["PostalCode"].value == null))
{
     alert("Postal Code is required!");
     return false;
}
```

and rename the form's postal code input to **postalCode** i.e.

```
<input type="text" name="postalCode" maxlength="25" /><i id="star">*</i>
```

Note that the validateForm function isn't checking the state. I assume you want it to be required because of the asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the tick mark after the closing brace in below code.

```
if ((document.forms["myForm"]["street"].value == "") || (document.forms["myForm"]["street"].value == null))
{
    alert("Street is required!");
    return false;
}**`**
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your form elements (input, buttons etc) are not within the form html element. There a 2 changes you need to make:

- Remove the back tick (`) in the JavaScript.
- Change your form element so that you only have an opening html element (from this: `<form/>` to `<form>` and close it after the table with `</form>`

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s9wk1kez/ (scroll to the right on the output panel)

Also as previously commented you have multiple ID in the mark-up which is invalid html. If you want to have working labels. (In that you can click on them for radio buttons and they correspond to the associated button) you should look at the documention for labels. For example `<label for="[id-of-html-element]">Male</label>`